# Library, which is depdendency of another library, not recognized in cordova run android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Im creating a plugin which will need a library (fullCamera) which uses another library (ecoGallery)
If I run my demo project on the command line `cordova run android`, the second gallery isn't recognized (`package us.feras.ecogallery does not exist`). But if I run on Eclipse, the project works as it should.

Does anyone ever faced something like this? Any suggestion?

The ecoGallery library is inside the fullCamera library, so, the app's `project.properties` requires fullCamera and fullCamera's `project.properties` requires ecoGallery.

Comment: looks like a bug, file an issue on the cordova jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/

Comment: Filed as bug, just in case

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this?

```
<dependency id="dependency_package_name"/> 

<dependency id="dependency_package_name" url="giturl"/>
```

in the plugin.xml file.

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification_dependency_element

Ok, found the docs. The dependency aren't in plugins, the libs are all inside the plugin

Comment: That's not the solution :-(